# Additional fields to results of INTERSECT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query that looks to match 6 fields between two tables and return the matches. This query uses inner joins. I've been testing INTERSECT to replace this. Thus,

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3,...,Field6
FROM TableA
INTERSECT
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3,...,Field6
FROM TableB
```

However, I want to add TableA.ID and TableB.ID to the results and can't quite get it written where the query won't take forever (relative to the original query).  Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:**
Regretfully, I added the comment about performance when the first concern is how to properly write the query.  As you can see, I believe the main issue is the very bad and incorrect query structure that I just haven't been able to improve. My attempt:

```
SELECT a.ID, b.ID    
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3,...,Field6
  FROM TableA
  INTERSECT
  SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3,...,Field6
  FROM TableB
) Dupes ON
(
  a.Field1 = Dupes.Field1 and
  ...
  a.Field6 = Dupes.Field6
)
INNER JOIN TableB b
(
  b.Field1 = Dupes.Field1 and
  ...
  b.Field6 = Dupes.Field6
)
```

Comment: What sort of indexes do you have on the two tables? I'm guessing the IDs are the primary keys? Also what does the execution plan show when it takes forever?

Comment: The IDs are primary keys and they are currently the only indexes on the tables. I can tell my current attempt is incorrect (too many rows returned) and thus I am first looking for a correct query. I am trying to decipher the execution plan as I can, but I am no expert there.

Comment: Could you please show the exact sql you are executing that is taking so long?

Comment: It's fine. I'm just trying to get the most info so that me and others can help you better. The query performance depends on a bunch of factors like indexes and how your data tables are structured. Showing the exact sql query (with the table.ID) and posting a picture of your executing plan will be very helpful :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `INNER JOIN` on all 6 fields will return all records from both tables having common field values:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.ID, A.Field1, A.Field2, A.Field3, A.Field4, 
       A.Field5, A.Field6
FROM TableA AS A
INNER JOIN TableB AS B 
ON A.Field1 = B.Field1 AND A.Field2 = B.Field2 AND A.Field3 = B.Field3 AND 
   A.Field4 = B.Field4 AND A.Field5 = B.Field5 AND A.Field6 = B.Field6
```

To optimize the above query you need to set indices on all columns used in the `ON` clause of the `INNER JOIN`.